# jQuery - Hide table if it contains 1 <tr> and 1 <td> containing &nbsp;

Tags: jquery

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can a i structure a jQuery selector in such a way that it will look for a table with a cell containing `&nbsp;` and set the table to `display: none;`

Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('table').each(function ()
{
    var $table = $(this),
        numTRs = $table.find('tr').length,
        $tds = $table.find('td'),
        numTDs = $tds.length;

    if (numTRs === 1 && numTDs === 1 && $tds.html() === '&nbsp;')
    {
        $table.hide();
    }
});
```

Test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WhAcB/

Comment: Hmm.. this doesnt seem to work either http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/tq3TQ/1/ the text for nbsp; shows up as just a blank space.

Comment: change `$tds.text() === '&nbsp;'` to  `$tds.html() === '&nbsp;' `and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6xGRM/1/

Answer (score 0):

This will work according to specs and is still pure Jquery:

```
$('table tr:only-child td:only-child').filter(function () {
         return $(this).html() === '&nbsp;';}).closest("table").hide();
```

What troubled me was the special character in the table. Otherwise it would be simpler.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('table tr:only-child td:only-child:contains("nbsp")').closest("table").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: You would think this would work. But it doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/tq3TQ/

Comment: That doesn't check the condition of the table containing exactly 1 `<tr>` and 1 `<td>`.

Comment: "Looks like" is not the same as Exactly ;-)

Comment: I inferred this from the title.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/f7N8Y/)

```
$('table').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var trCount = $this.find('tr').length;
    var tdCount = $this.find('td').length;

    if (trCount == 1 && tdCount == 1) {
        var tdContents = $this.find('td:first').html();
        if (tdContents == '&nbsp;') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.hide();
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
});
```